# How to map ComplexType of EF6 in base class to derived class table in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-fluent-api

Our system is existed and upgrading into EF Core

We have an EntityBase class for all entities to inheritance, but every derived class has its own key "Sid"

EntityBase.cs

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    // some other properties
    public UpdateInfo UpdateInfo { get; set;}
}
```

UpdateInfo.cs

```
public class UpdateInfo
{
    // some other properties
    public string CreatedBy;
}
```

All business entities class is like

```
public class BusinessEntity: EntityBase
{
    // some own properties
}
```

Now in our original database, every UpdateInfo will map to the derived class table as **"UpdateInfo_CreatedBy"** using EF 6 ComplexType with column constraint. Table will be like:

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVqUX.png)

But I don't know how to map to the original database with EF Core fluent API in "OnModelCreating" with bulk configuration without changing the original database table structure and original business class definition.

## **EDIT:**

I finally found out how bulk configuration works and successfully made the UpdateInfo normally Add-Migration

Comment: You can manipulate the entire model in `OnModelCreating`, starting with something like `foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()){ ... }`

Comment: I think the simplest answer is `[Owned] public class UpdateInfo {}`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I have tried [Owned] (and of course OwnsOne in modelBuilder) but I get error 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'BusinessClass.UpdateInfo' to type 'UpdateInfo' ' when Add-Migration